# Preventing network call while calling `date::make_zoned()`

Tags: c++, date

While connected to the web, the following program, which converts a given `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` to a string, takes a whopping `1s32ms` to complete. However, if my machine is not connected to the web, the program requires a reasonable `54ms`.

```
#include "date/tz.h" // Howard Hinnant's date library
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

std::string tp2str(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point &tp,
                                 const std::string &tz) {
    auto z = date::make_zoned(tz, tp);
    return date::format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z (%A)", z);
}

int main() {
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << tp2str(now, "US/Eastern") << std::endl;
}
```

Examining the profiler output while connected reveals that the delay is on account of the function sequence `date::remote_version ... Curl_http_connect` which presumably attempts to connect to a remote web host.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour while calling `date::make_zoned()` while still being connected to the web?

Comment: Well maybe the problem is in the mysterious `date::make_zoned()` function, which apparently comes from the `date/tz.h` header in your application. I'm not quite sure how anyone who's not in possession of the entire source code to your C++ program could tell you anything more (and, no, that's not an invitation to post all of it to Stackoverflow).

Comment: It's Howard Hinnant's well-known `date` library. See the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for Howard Hinnant's `date` library explains `remote_version()`, explains what it is for, and how to turn it off. I'll quote from the [documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html):

> The following functions are available only if you compile with the configuration macro HAS_REMOTE_API == 1. Use of this API requires linking to libcurl. AUTO_DOWNLOAD == 1 requires HAS_REMOTE_API == 1. You will be notified at compile time if AUTO_DOWNLOAD == 1 and HAS_REMOTE_API == 0. If HAS_REMOTE_API == 1, then AUTO_DOWNLOAD defaults to 1, otherwise AUTO_DOWNLOAD defaults to 0. On Windows, HAS_REMOTE_API defaults to 0. Everywhere else it defaults to 1. This is because libcurl comes preinstalled everywhere but Windows, but it is available for Windows.
>
> None of these are available with USE_OS_TZDB == 1.

Most likely, you want to add a compile-time definition `USE_OS_TZDB=1` to your build.

Comment: That sounds plausible. However, I tried adding `set(USE_OS_TZDB 1)` to my `CMakeLists.txt` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't personally use nor recommend CMake with this library.  Here are the installation instructions I recommend: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation  If you must use CMake, then you must be good with it, and able to translate the instructions at https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation to your CMake file.

Comment: I'll translate for you: `target_compile_definitions(<yourtargetname> PUBLIC USE_OS_TZDB=1)` . You need to **compile** with that `USE_OS_TZDB` define, not set-a-CMake-variable.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone's interested in the `CMakeLists.txt`, here's what works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(date_test)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0077 NEW)

include( FetchContent )
FetchContent_Declare( date
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date.git
        GIT_TAG        v3.0.1
        )
set( BUILD_TZ_LIB ON CACHE INTERNAL "build/install of TZ library")
set( USE_SYSTEM_TZ_DB ON CACHE INTERNAL "Use the operating system's timezone database" )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(date)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE date-tz)
```

where note the overrides for `BUILD_TZ_LIB` and `USE_SYSTEM_TZ_DB` `cmake` variables set in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) repo.